# Nice squares related to each other

Tags: matrices

A ***nice square*** of order $\,n\,$ is a square matrix with $\,n\,$ rows and $\,n\,$ columns such that any integer $\,i=1,2,\ldots,n\,$ only appears one time in every row and in every column.
Let $\,a_{ij}$ be the entry of a *nice square* in the $\,i^{\mathrm{th}}$ row and in the $\,j^{\mathrm{th}}$ column.
We say that two *nice squares* $\,A\,$ and $\,B\,$ of order $\,n\,$ are **related** if the $\,n^2$ ordered pairs $\,(a_{ij},b_{ij})\,$ are all different, that is, there do not exist two ordered pairs $\,(a_{ij},b_{ij})\,$ and $\,(a_{hk},b_{hk})\,$ such that $\,(a_{ij},b_{ij})= (a_{hk},b_{hk})\,$ but $\,(i,j)\neq(h,k)\,.$

I would like to prove that for any $\,n\geqslant3\,$ the number of *nice squares related* to each other is less than or equal to $\,n-1\,.$

**My attempt:**

I tried to prove it by induction by $\,n\,$.
For $\,n=3\,$ I got the following two *related nice squares*:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\2&3&1\\3&1&2\end{bmatrix}$

and

$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\3&1&2\\2&3&1\end{bmatrix}\;.$

By inspection I found out that there does not exist any *nice square* $\,C\,$ *related* to both $\,A\,$ and $\,B\,.$

So the number of *nice squares related* to each other has to be equal to $\,n-1=2\,.$

Then, I supposed that the property is true for the *nice squares* of order $\,n-1\,$ (induction hypothesis) and tried to prove that the property is also true for the *nice squares* of order $\,n\,.$

But notwithstanding my efforts I did not manage to prove it.

Could you help me prove that for any $\,n\geqslant3\,$ the number of *nice squares related* to each other is less than or equal to $\,n-1\;?$

**I have written an answer containing a proof.

Could you tell me if my proof is correct or if it contains some mistake ?**

Comment: Why have you downvoted my question ?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted or why, but nice squares are more commonly known as *Latin squares*

Comment: The common term for related to each other is 'orthogonal'

Comment: The result is definitely true, you cannot have more than $n-1$ mutually orthogonal latin squares. There are proofs on wikipedia and other places. For some $n$, we cannot even get all the way up to $n-1$. It is known how to do it if $n$ is a prime power. Conversely, at the other extreme we have $n=6$ where it is known that one cannot even find 2 orthogonal latin squares. The first case where it is open what the maximum number of mutually orthogonal latin squares is is $n = 10$. You could get quite famous in some circles if you could solve that one.

Comment: I did not look at your proof in dept, maybe I will do it later, but the result is true as I said

Answer (score 1):

I am going to prove that for any $\,n\geqslant3\,$ the number of *nice squares related* to each other is less than or equal to  $\,n-1\,.$

**Proof:**

Firstly, we consider all the *nice squares* whose first row is $\color{brown}{\;1\;2\;\ldots\;n}:$

$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&\ldots&n\\a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2n}\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\ldots&a_{nn}\end{bmatrix}\;,\quad$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&\ldots&n\\b_{21}&b_{22}&\ldots&b_{2n}\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\b_{n1}&b_{n2}&\ldots&b_{nn}\end{bmatrix}\;,\;\;\cdots\;.$

Since the number $\,1\,$ appears in the first column of each matrix, it follows that $\,a_{21}\neq1\,,\,$ $b_{21}\neq1\,,\,\ldots\,,\,$ consequently there are $\,n-1\,$ possibilities for $\,a_{21}\,$ which are :

$a_{21}=2\;\lor\;a_{21}=3\;\lor\;\ldots\;\lor\;a_{21}=n\;.$

Moreover, two different *nice squares* which have the same entry in the $\,2^{\mathrm{nd}}$ row and in the $\,1^{\mathrm{st}}$ column (for example $\,a_{21}=b_{21}=k\,$) cannot be *related* to each other because the ordered pairs $\,(a_{1k},b_{1k})\,,\,$ $(a_{21},b_{21})\,$ are not different, indeed $\,(a_{1k},b_{1k})=(k,k)=(a_{21},b_{21})\,.$

Hence, the number of the *nice squares related* to each other, whose first row is $\color{brown}{\;1\;2\;\ldots\;n}\,,\,$ cannot be greater than the number $\,n-1\,$ of the different possibilities of $\,a_{21}\,.$

On the other hand, for any *nice square*

$M=\begin{bmatrix}m_{11}&m_{12}&\ldots&m_{1i}&\ldots&m_{1n}\\m_{21}&m_{22}&\ldots&m_{2i}&\ldots&m_{2n}\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\m_{n1}&m_{n2}&\ldots&m_{ni}&\ldots&m_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$

there exists $\,i\in\{2,3,\ldots,n\}\,$ such that $\,m_{21}=m_{1i}\;,$

consequently ,

$M\,$ cannot be *related* to

$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&\ldots&i&\ldots&n\\a_{21}\!=\!i&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2i}&\ldots&a_{2n}\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\ldots&a_{ni}&\ldots&a_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$

which is one of the $\,n-1\,$ *nice squares* whose first row is $\color{brown}{\;1\;2\;\ldots\;n}\;,$

because the ordered pairs $\,(m_{1i},a_{1i})\,,\,$ $(m_{21},a_{21})\,$ are not different, indeed $\,(m_{1i},a_{1i})=(m_{1i},i)=(m_{21},a_{21})\,.$

Therefore ,

it is impossible to get more than $\,n-1\,$ *nice squares related* to each other.